# How to list the tree structure in Unix

Tags: unix, putty

I have access to unix server from Putty application. Can anyone tell me how can I view/print all the files and directories inside a directory.

I tried below by searching internet and not working. Not sure what actually they do!

```
find ./ -type d | awk -F "/" '{ ld=0x2500; lt=0x251c; ll=0x2502; for (i=1; i<=NF-2; i++){printf "%c    ",ll} printf "%c%c %s\n",lt,ld,$NF }'
```

and this

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Comment: `ls -laR /path/to/list`

Answer (score 1):

The tool tree will help you, while at it, you might also want to install pstree.

```
19:38:05 dusted@mono~
$ tree test
test
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── b
│   ├── 1
│   ├── b
│   └── c
├── b-files.txt
├── new-b-files.txt
├── newer-b-files.txt
└── test

2 directories, 10 files
```

Comment: I am not sure why! I am getting `tree: Command not found` error when running from putty..

Comment: You need to install the program in order to run it.

Comment: @Rams then ask the administrator of the machine (the person who has root access or sudo access) to install it for you, putty is simply an SSH client, the program you are interfacing to through it is the systems command shell, which surely is capable of anything you could dream up, as long as it is within the privileges of your user on that system.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I did a little searching and stumbled upon a site that explains what you are asking. Let us know if this leads you in the right direction...http://www.centerkey.com/tree/

Answer (score 0):

The 'find' command should do the job:

```
find /path/to/directory
```

If you want more information for each entry, you can combine 'find' with 'ls' like this:

```
find /path/to/directory -exec ls -ld "{}" \;
```